# Finding minimum and maximum in a list of tuples i.e (min,max),(max,min)?

Tags: python, tuples, max, min

I have a list of tuples, (x1,y1),(x2,y2) etc and what I'd like to find is the tuple where x is a maximum and y is a minimum and various other combinations. I have been able to find where x is a maximum and y is a maximum, and when x is a minimum and y is a minimum, but I'm not sure how to first filter by maximum, then by minimum and vice versa.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
coords = [(200,200),(40,150),(50,180),(20,200),(200,20),(20,20)]

c1 = max(coords, key=operator.itemgetter(0))
c2 = min(coords,key = operator.itemgetter(0))
c3 = max(coords,key = operator.itemgetter(1))
c4 = min(coords,key = operator.itemgetter(1))

#returns (200,200),(20,200),(200,200),(200,20))
#wanted (200,200),(20,200), (200, 20), (20,20) 
#(max,max), (min,max), (max,min), (min,min) or some order of this
```

In reality 'coords' has more than 6 tuples. I end up with the same coordinate being returned for c1 and c3 for example when I wanted coords[0] and coords[3], so (max,max) and then (min,max). Am I over-complicating things, or is there a much simpler way to solve this? The order of the output doesn't particularly matter as long as it is the same order every time the coords change. I have simplified this issue to post here so there may be some errors sorry.  Thanks!

Comment: This is a terrible example because the input is the same as the intended output. Please change the test case.

Comment: Sorry, I added two more coordinates, hopefully it makes more sense now.

Comment: would you want to keep `(20,150)`? Is 200 always max and 20 always min? is the max a set number of it just equal to the max value of the tuples? is max separate for x and y?

Comment: What would you want for `[(1,2), (2,3), (3,2), (2,1)]`?

Comment: Nope I just want 4 co-ordinates returned. As far as I know there will always be 4 coordinates where the minimum x and minimum y are the same and vice versa. Even if coords had 100+ tuples, somewhere there would be (max,max), (min,max), (max,min), (min,min) where min and max for x and y are always the same value. So in this case minimum x and y is 20, and maximum x and y is 200.

Comment: So just find (min,min) and (max,max) and build the other two from them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible approach is to identify the maximum and minimum values of x and y, generate all possible tuples with those values, and check if those tuples exist in the list.

```
coords = [(200,200),(20,200),(200,20),(20,20)]
max_x = max([t[0] for t in coords])
min_x = min([t[0] for t in coords])
max_y = max([t[1] for t in coords])
min_y = min([t[1] for t in coords])

for x in [min_x,max_x]:
  for y in [min_y,max_y]:
     if (x,y) in coords:
       print( (x,y) )
```

Given your clarifying comments, I think that's sufficient for your needs. If the input data didn't reliably contain the combinations you're looking for, you'd have to be more specific about what you want.

For that matter, if you are guaranteed that the combinations you want are in the input data, you could remove the `if` line and just output all of the permutations.  But it's probably wise to verify they are actually there.

Comment: Thank you! This is mostly what I am looking for, I just didn't know if there was a neater way of doing things without loops. But this clears a lot up, so thanks.

Comment: Actually their comments suggest `min_x, min_y = min(coords)` and same for max.